# Can only add entity kinds/attributes if they already exist in GAE dev server

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I am unsure if this is a bug, by design (though I can't see the benefit), or if I am just being dimwitted.

Using Google App Engine development server, v1.9.8, I can only add a datastore entity if another of the same kind already exists. Otherwise the drop-down physically does not show the entity kind.

Further, even on an entity kind that does exist, I can only change attributes (or create them if it's new) if that attribute is not null on at least one of the other existing entities of that kind.

This is annoying, since in order to test things I have to first do:

```
entityKind(every=Possible, attribute=Set, to=Something, even=If,
    i=Dont, yet=Need).put()
```

Refresh, and then remember to delete this line before refreshing again to avoid duplicating the entry in datastore.

Note though, that if I happen to be testing with only entities that do not use every attribute, I have to keep this dummy one just in case I want the others later.

I *must*, surely, be missing something here? I can't believe there isn't a way to just create datastore entities without hacking around it like this?

Comment: write a unit test :) it won't be duplicate if you define a key, and you do not need to put that line in your code, you can simply create the entity via remote api.

Comment: @marcadian Only works if the app's live at appspot.com

Comment: which part? remote api works on localhost too does not need to be on live server

Answer (score 2):

You are talking about creating entities manually using a Dev server. Over the past 4 years of using GAE I wished once or twice that this would be possible, but I never *needed* this feature. You create entities in your code, and you debug your code if something does not work.

You can (and should) write unit tests to test your code. A proper unit test creates an entity, saves it, reads it, verifies that all the properties are correct, deletes it, verifies that it was deleted. There is no code to cut and paste (or comment/uncomment), and there are no test entities left after testing is completed.

Comment: It would be especially useful to me though since I am only just starting... I need to test what I've done so far works every few steps, otherwise I'm going to write a load of useless spaghetti, and it'll be nigh on impossible to see where the errors are. E.g. if I have a list of users displayed, I want to add some users and make sure it looks right without yet having implemented a new user signup (just a trivial example - solution isn't always so easily 'do it the other way around').

Comment: Understood. You can write a "startup" script which populates tables with the initial set of data that you need for testing before the other functionality is completed. It's much faster than creating a new entity manually every time you need it. Will your app look correctly with 50 users? What if a user creates 100 messages? What if you made a mistake and now you need to re-create all of the entities? Etc. Creating entities in code is a few lines of code. Creating them manually will take forever.

Comment: Even creating them in code, It's still listing one of the `db.ReferenceProperty`s as '(None)' - if I manually set it again, it is just 'forgotten'. I am using the same method of `refattr=otherModel().put()` as is working for another property of that type. What can be the problem?

Answer (score 2):

Your mistake is in thinking of the web console as a part of your workflow. It is absolutely not, and not intended to be. It is a vaguely hacked-together tool that allows you to do some basic operations on your data, and nothing else.

Interact with the datastore via code, and leave the web console for simple verifications.

Comment: I understand, I just think it would be so much quicker for some basic things I'm testing. e.g. if a particular property on a certain entity is True, I have a couple of divs one way around, and the other if False. Changing the value of a drop down is quicker than even just one line of code, at least for me.

Comment: you should write your own admin UI in that case. It'll be a good experience and not that hard if you use, for example, something like WTForms which can generate HTML from GAE models.